# Are empty post slugs useful?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

In my WordPress blog I am facing some issues because of **old post slugs**, So I searched and deleted old post slugs in MySQL but the database has many **empty old post slugs**, I don't know about them.
So my real question is that **"Can I delete empty old post slugs? Is there any harm if I delete them?"**

Comment: What if you back up, delete, test, (restore)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comment  by Jan Dvorak, I tested and deleted all the empty `wp_old_slugs` and everything seems fine.

But sure I don't know why these slugs ere empty?